# Pandas read_json() encoding = 'utf-8-sig' option is not working for BytesIO object (file-like object)

Tags: python, pandas

When trying to load a [jsonlines](https://jsonlines.org/) file encoded in UTF8-BOM as Bytes data directly into pandas dataframe, getting error 'ValueError' object has no attribute 'message' (this generic error happens when encoding is different). I am trying to read data from Azure Datalake Gen-2 using azure.storage.filedatalake.DataLakeFileClient and it gives me bytes data and i am trying to load that data into pandas dataframe directly.The code snippet failing is given below

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from io import BytesIO,StringIO 



def initialize_storage_account_ad(storage_account_name, client_id, client_secret, tenant_id):
    
    try:  
        global service_client

        credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)

        service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
            "https", storage_account_name), credential=credential)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.message)

initialize_storage_account_ad(storage_account_name, client_id, client_secret, tenant_id)
data_folder = '/raw/data/'

file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="dls")
paths = file_system_client.get_paths(path=data_folder)

directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client(data_folder)

file_client = directory_client.get_file_client('API_COUNTRY.json')
download = file_client.download_file()

downloaded_bytes = download.readall()
df = pd.read_json(BytesIO(downloaded_bytes),lines = True,encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
display(df)
```

The same code works if i try with UTF-8 encoding, also if i write UTF8-BOM jsonlines to a file and load it using `df = pd.read_json('country.json',lines = True,encoding = 'utf-8-sig')` then also it works. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Error StackTrace

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-b150d9150c5a> in <module>
     31 
     32 downloaded_bytes = download.readall()
---> 33 df = pd.read_json(BytesIO(downloaded_bytes),lines = True,encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
     34 display(df)

C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    197                 else:
    198                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 199             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    200 
    201         return cast(F, wrapper)

C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    294                 )
    295                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 296             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    297 
    298         return wrapper

C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines, chunksize, compression, nrows)
    616         return json_reader
    617 
--> 618     result = json_reader.read()
    619     if should_close:
    620         filepath_or_buffer.close()

C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in read(self)
    751                 data = ensure_str(self.data)
    752                 data = data.split("\n")
--> 753                 obj = self._get_object_parser(self._combine_lines(data))
    754         else:
    755             obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)

C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in _get_object_parser(self, json)
    775         obj = None
    776         if typ == "frame":
--> 777             obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
    778 
    779         if typ == "series" or obj is None:

C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in parse(self)
    884 
    885         else:
--> 886             self._parse_no_numpy()
    887 
    888         if self.obj is None:

C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
   1117         if orient == "columns":
   1118             self.obj = DataFrame(
-> 1119                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1120             )
   1121         elif orient == "split":

ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Beginning of the bytes values:

```
('b', ['0xef', '0xbb', '0xbf', '0x7b', '0x22', '0x49', '0x44', '0x45', '0x4e', '0x54', '0x49', '0x46', '0x49', '0x45', '0x52', '0x22', '0x3a', '0x22', '0x41', '0x66', '0x67', '0x68', '0x61', '0x6e', '0x69', '0x73', '0x74', '0x61', '0x6e', '0x22', '0x2c', '0x22', '0x49', '0x44', '0x45', '0x4e', '0x54', '0x49', '0x46', '0x49', '0x45', '0x52', '0x5f', '0x49', '0x53', '0x4f', '0x32', '0x22', '0x3a', '0x22', '0x41', '0x46', '0x22', '0x2c', '0x22', '0x49', '0x44', '0x45', '0x4e', '0x54', '0x49', '0x46', '0x49', '0x45', '0x52', '0x5f', '0x49', '0x53', '0x4f', '0x33', '0x22', '0x3a', '0x22', '0x41', '0x46', '0x47', '0x22', '0x2c', '0x22', '0x49', '0x44', '0x45', '0x4e', '0x54', '0x49', '0x46', '0x49', '0x45', '0x52', '0x5f', '0x49', '0x53', '0x4f', '0x5f', '0x4e', '0x55', '0x4d', '0x45', '0x52', '0x49', '0x43', '0x22', '0x3a', '0x22', '0x30', '0x30', '0x34', '0x22', '0x2c', '0x22', '0x4f', '0x46', '0x46', '0x49', '0x43', '0x49', '0x41', '0x4c', '0x5f', '0x53', '0x48', '0x4f', '0x52', '0x54', '0x5f', '0x49', '0x44', '0x45'])
```

Comment: Add the error traceback to your question.

Comment: You are only using pandas in the last line. Most of your code seems to use an azure storage library. But you are referring to `service_client` that is never defined in your code. And you are importing and defining stuff that you never use. Your code sample is not complete and not minimal [mcve].

Comment: You should show the beginning of `downloaded bytes`: `print(('c', [hex(ord(i)) for i in downloaded_bytes[:128]]) if isinstance(downloaded_bytes, str) else ('b', [hex(i) for i in downloaded_bytes[:128]]))`

Comment: @HåkenLid : Updated the example, basically error is easily reproducible if we read a UTF8-BOM jsonlines file into bytes object and load into pandas dataframe using (BytesIO)

Comment: @HåkenLid   `in_file = open("my_file.json", "rb") # UTF8-BOM encoded , jsonlines file
downloaded_bytes = in_file.read()
in_file.close()
df = pd.read_json(BytesIO(downloaded_bytes),lines = True,encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
display(df) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in older Pandas versions. With a minimal JsonL bytestring utf-8-sig encoded in `bb`, I tried:

```
pd.read_json(io.BytesIO(bb), lines=True, encoding='utf-8-sig') (1)
pd.read_json(io.StringIO(bb.decode('utf-8-sig')), lines=True)  (2)
```

Both work fine on Python 3.8 Pandas 1.2.2, but on Python 3.6 Pandas 1.0.3 (2) works fine but (1) raises `ValueError: Expected object or value`

It means that the workaround is trivial: decode your bytestring at Python level and feed `read_json` with a unicode string:

```
...
downloaded_bytes = download.readall()
df = pd.read_json(StringIO(downloaded_bytes.decode('utf-8-sig')),lines = True)
display(df)
```

Comment: i am using pandas 1.1.5 and Python 3.6. Thank you for the detailed explanation, decoding the bytes object using utf8-bom and creating Text Stream did worked like a charm.

Comment: I had the same issue on AML. Specifying pandas==1.4.1 on the pip install helped overcome this.